# Setting Object as a value to <form:option> in Spring MVC

Tags: java, forms, spring-mvc

I am using Spring 3.2.1-RELEASE Library to develop a application...

Is it possible to set an object as value for ..

eg:

```
<form:select path="var">
  <form:option value=Object1>One</form:option>
  <form:option value=Object2>Two</form:option>
</form:select>
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I dont think, you can do that

Comment: yes you cna do that, thats the point of the spring form (if they are omplex objects you need serialization/conversion sorted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible.

What you can do is have a Map in your Controller with key as Object name and Value as Object itself. Then based on the selected Object name retrieve the Object.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set values in Model object, in Controller side and the parse the values in jsp using JSTL and fill the values

Mock code can be found in this SO question

[How to pass an object from Spring 3.0 controller to JSP view and test with JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255352/how-to-pass-an-object-from-spring-3-0-controller-to-jsp-view-and-test-with-jstl)